# Specifying char width and compression type programatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, benchmarking

In SQL Server 2008, consider the table

```
create table myTable (id int, filler char(X)) with (data_compression = Y)
```

where X is an integer of varying size, and Y is either "row", "page" or "none". In an experiment, I would like to specify X and Y programatically in T-SQL, so that I can measure a number of performance metrics for a large (!) amount of different (X,Y) pairs.

However, the following is not allowed:

```
declare @mySize int = 100
create table myTable (id int, filler char(@mySize)) ...
```

How can I then specify the char width and compression type programatically?

Comment: For many portions of DML/DDL you will need to use dynamic SQL. EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE ... char(' + RTRIM(@mySize) + '));';

Comment: Define "large" please? 100 million+?

Comment: @marc_s: As I wrote in the question, it is for use in benchmarking, not in an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL, for example:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'create table myTable (id int, filler char(' + 
    cast(@X as varchar(12)) + ')) with (compression = ' + @Y + ')'
exec (@sql)
```